# hazelcast doesn't delete queue after ttl time

Tags: java, spring, queue, hazelcast

I have hazelcast configuration with spring where I set empty-queue-ttl 5. By script on H web-manager I check that property was set correctly. But I have more then 15 empty not active queues.

What causes this situation?

- invoke q.destroy method with error before ?
- hazelcast issue ?
- something else?

Realy, I don't know how to watch queue creation. but there is nothing in last actions list during last minute.

Regarding to documentation queues must be removed

Comment: As far as I can follow your question, you expect the queue to be removed when TTL expires? Can you provide a link/quote where this is stated in the docs?

Comment: I used this knowledges http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.4/manual/html/queueconfiguration.html

Comment: The docs seem to claim that the queue will be destroyed if the queue is not _used_ during the TTL period. I guess that includes any access, including polling. How do you ensure that the queues aren't touched in any way, not just that they stay empty?

Comment: This functionality is present in hazelcast mancenter. Watch polls, offers, memory for each queue, maps...

Comment: Here is a code snippet which runs fine (3.6-SNAPSHOT)
https://gist.github.com/gurbuzali/d8e83db2f24a9f73359d

A small thing, the queue is scheduled for eviction after first interaction with the queue. If you create a queue and don't do anything with it then it will not get evicted.